# Spree admin panel not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I've install Spree gem and run it as it wrote in Getting Started. All works fine but if I want to go in the Products section in admin panel I have the following error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'variants.position' in 'order clause': SELECT `variants`.* FROM `variants` WHERE (`variants`.product_id IN (706676762,569012001,723959550,1025786064,1060500592,248786582,187438981,1035865702,459084718) AND (variants.is_master = 0 AND variants.deleted_at IS NULL)) ORDER BY variants.position ASC
```

Anyone faced that?

EDIT: Here is my Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.7'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.2.11'
gem 'heroku'
gem 'thin'
gem 'spree', '~> 0.60.0'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger (ruby-debug for Ruby 1.8.7+, ruby-debug19 for Ruby 1.9.2+)
# gem 'ruby-debug'
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

# Bundle the extra gems:
# gem 'bj'
# gem 'nokogiri'
# gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
# gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
# group :development, :test do
#   gem 'webrat'
# end
gem "test", :path => "test", :require => "test"
```

Comment: Did you have a migration named "date"_add_position_to_variants.rb ?

Comment: Inside your db/migrate folder :)

Comment: 20090923100315_add_count_on_hand_to_variants_and_products.rb. No, there no such file inside db/migrate ^(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally when you install spree by following these [steps](http://spreecommerce.com/documentation/getting_started.html), you should have some migration files inside db/migrate, one of them contain the missing column for your application :

```
class AddPositionToVariants < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :variants, :position, :integer
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :variants, :position
  end
end
```

Comment: I've added that code to the new_migration.rb and run rake db:migrate, but error appears again. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: have you correctly follow the spree tutorial to start a new application ? If yes can you add the error in your question ? :)

Comment: Yes, I've follow official Spree getting started. The error is the same as in my first post

Comment: When you rake:db:migrate the first time did you have some errors ?

Comment: I've delete all the projet and recreate it again... it works now o_O

Comment: Something don't work the first time :) good luck with spree !